# Aplicación web aspx sin conexión a internet: offline

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, iis

Eh buscado por internet información de HTML5 que permite poner offline una aplicación web, pero mi aplicación está programada con aspx. También seguí los pasos que vienen en ésta [página](https://www.arkaitzgarro.com/html5/capitulo-9.html) pero al subirla al IIS he intentar probrar usar una página de mi sitio sin conexión pues no hace nada.

**ASPX:**

```
<html lang="en" manifest="/appoffline.appcache" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
    <head runat="server">
    ...
    <script>
      function testOnline(fn) {
          var script = document.createElement(‘script’)
          script.src = 'online.js';
          window.setOnline = function (online) {
              document.body.removeChild(script);
              fn(online);
          };
          document.body.appendChild(script);
      }

      testOnline(function (online) {
          if (online) {
               applicationCache.update();
          } else {
          }
      });
      if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker
             .register('/sw.js')
             .then(function() { console.log("Service Worker Registered"); });
      }
      </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

El script sirve para identificar si el usuario tiene o no internet. Ésta configuración la utilicé para la página Login nada más.

**appoffline.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v1 - 2018-07-06
CACHE:
Login.aspx
Style.css
Images/ab1.png

FALLBACK:
online.js offline.js
```

En IIS ya tengo el MIME instalado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: imagino que si hay una comunicación local con el servidor....

Comment: Si, la aplicación funciona bien, pero no al momento de desactivar el internet.

Comment: me suena a problema del DNS, que dirección utilizas para navegar a la aplicación ? probablemente tendrás que hacerlo directamente por dirección IP

Comment: www.catavina.com.mx y si lo hago por IP pasa lo mismo ://

Comment: Tienes que usar la IP interna, o el nombre del servidor, tambien si tienes algun redirect que estos tengan la ip 
calavina.com.mx es en definitiva un nombre de proveedor externo, ese no funcionara cuando apagues el internet